# How to use external identities for authorization on GCloud App Engin

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a very simple sign-in page that accepts Google, Microsoft and e-mail/ password for an App Engine application.
I followed this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/cloud-run-sign-in

I managed to get IAP up and running, with a working Google login page. But I couldn't get the login page with External Identity Providers to work.

Ater activating the External Providers, I try to test the IAP, but a page with  this error loads:
"A specified resource is not found, or the request is rejected by undisclosed reasons."

Edit with more details:
I followed these two guides:
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enable-external-identities
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/cloud-run-sign-in

Steps:

1. Open the IAP page in the Cloud Console.
2. Select the same project that you configured Identity Platform with. Using different projects is not supported.
3. Select the HTTP Resources tab.
4. Locate the App Engine app or Compute Engine service you want to restrict access to using IAP.
5. Toggle the switch in the IAP column to On.
6. In the side panel, click Start in the box labeled Use external identities for authorization.
7. Confirm your selection.
8. In the Identity Platform side panel:
   a. Choose whether to build your own sign-in page, or have IAP create one for you. Letting IAP create the sign-in page is the fastest way to get started. **You don't need to deploy additional services or write any new code**, and can specify minor customizations using JSON. See Hosting an authentication UI on Cloud Run to learn more.
   c. Select whether to use project providers or tenants.
   d. Check the boxes of the providers or tenants to enable. Select Configure providers if you need to modify your providers or tenants.
9. Click Save.

And from the second guide:

1. Enable external identities, and select the Host a sign-in page for me option during setup.
2. Navigate to a resource protected by IAP. You should be automatically redirected to the sign-in page.

I managed to setup the External Identity Providers and GCP says it's status OK.
Th guide says "You don't need to deploy additional services or write any new code", but when I get to thee last step to test the sign-in page, the page only displays this error:
"A specified resource is not found, or the request is rejected by undisclosed reasons."

I found no more explanation about the error, and I can't see any steps missing.

What else needs to be done to get the login page working?

Comment: What did you do, and what did you configure? There is too few context to understand what happens!!

Comment: I edited my post with more details and all the steps I followed.